# Problem with screen resolution on Debian Buster Coffee Lake processor

Tags: debian, drivers, intel-graphics

I have problem with video driver.
I have

- Processor: Intel Core i7-8700K CPU @ 3.70 GHz x 6
- Graphics Card: Intel Corporation Device 3e92 (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])

And current Debian Buster distro.

```
# uname -a
Linux tanya 4.14.0-2-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.14.7-1 (2017-12-22) x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Here /var/log/Xorg.0.log:

```
[    10.481] (II) modesetting: Driver for Modesetting Kernel Drivers: kms
[    10.481] (II) FBDEV: driver for framebuffer: fbdev
[    10.482] (II) VESA: driver for VESA chipsets: vesa
[    10.485] (EE) open /dev/dri/card0: No such file or directory
[    10.485] (WW) Falling back to old probe method for modesetting
[    10.485] (EE) open /dev/dri/card0: No such file or directory
```

and lines:

```
[    10.486] (**) FBDEV(1): claimed PCI slot 0@0:2:0
[    10.486] (II) FBDEV(1): using default device
[    10.486] (WW) Falling back to old probe method for vesa
[    10.486] (EE) Screen 0 deleted because of no matching config section.
```

And this

```
# grep EE /var/log/Xorg.0.log
    (WW) warning, (EE) error, (NI) not implemented, (??) unknown.
[    10.485] (EE) open /dev/dri/card0: No such file or directory
[    10.485] (EE) open /dev/dri/card0: No such file or directory
[    10.486] (EE) Screen 0 deleted because of no matching config section.
[    10.494] (EE) AIGLX: reverting to software rendering
```

I have not xorg-file, I tryed install linux-image-amd64 firmware-misc-nonfree packages from contrib non-free repository buster, but it didn't help.

/var/log/kern.log (i915 keyword, time prefix removed):

```
[drm] The driver support for your hardware in this kernel version is alpha quality
See CONFIG_DRM_I915_ALPHA_SUPPORT or i915.alpha_support module parameter
to enable support in this kernel version, or check for kernel updates.
...
snd_hda_intel 0000:00:1f.3: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
snd_hda_intel 0000:00:1f.3: failed to add i915 component master (-19)
...
snd_hda_codec_hdmi hdaudioC0D2: No i915 binding for Intel HDMI/DP codec
snd_hda_codec_hdmi hdaudioC0D2: No i915 binding for Intel HDMI/DP codec
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Kernels 4.13 and 4.14 have support for Coffee Lake, but as an alpha, so you need to boot the kernel with

```
i915.alpha_support=1
```

You can do this by editing the kernel command line manually during the boot, or by editing `/etc/default/grub`’s `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT`. In the latter case, run `update-grub` before rebooting...

This won’t be necessary with kernel 4.15 which enables Coffee Lake support by default.

Comment: I guess the developers considered it potentially dangerous (because it wasn’t tested as well as they’d like, perhaps), so they wanted to avoid it being enabled by default... Without support, you could still boot to a text console, whereas with buggy support, you might not be able to boot at all.

Comment: I confirm this now worked for me, with Ubuntu 16.04 and an i7 8th gen. Also solves the screen remaining blank after a system suspend. For a slightly finer elucidation of the process may I recommend people also follow https://askubuntu.com/a/1002662/208696. Thanks a lot for this answer!!!

Comment: This doesn't work for me on Debian 9 with Kernel 4.14 from Stretch-backports. Any idea?

Comment: @Simon could you clarify what you mean by “doesn’t work”?

Comment: I meant that 3D acceleration does not work with Debian 9, Kernel 4.14 and `i915.alpha_support=1` kernel parameter. i3 8100 cpu. Everything else does work. Sorry for not being precise.

Comment: @Simon you’d be better off [asking](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) a new question, that will give you enough room to provide more details (and the question here isn’t about 3D per se).

Comment: @StephenKitt I would have been very happy to know  too. I am in the same situation as Simon and it does not work. GPU driver aren't installed. Did anyone succeeded on Debian stretch?

Comment: @BigDong feel free to [ask](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) a new question, Simon never did. This question is about Buster; the Debian 9 specifics are different and I haven’t looked into them in detail for Coffee Lake.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.  Even extended desktop didn't work. Only the dual monitors but with clone were working.

Now my dual monitors works with extended desktop with good resolution 1920x1080 each.

I have:

- Processor: Intel Core i5-8400 CPU @ 2.80GHz
- Graphics Card: Intel Corporation Device 3e92
- Motherboard: Gigabyte Z370 HD3

My solution was:

- Reinstall my PC with Debian Stretch, selecting the whole packages for gnome and kde  during installation so they installed all necessary graphic packages and drivers.
- After installation finished I added backports for that version to /etc/apt/sources.list:
  deb http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian stretch-backports main
- Then installed Kernel 4.18
  apt-get install linux-image-4.18.0-0.bpo.1-amd64
- Rebooted and voila!! my monitors worked with good resolution and extended desktop using kde.

Looks like for Kernel 4.18 is not necessary add any parameter to kernel boot or grub. It will enable Coffee Lake support by default.

I hope this works for you. I was struggling with this problem for a couple of days ;).

Cesar